# How do I properly enable auditing of operations on an Oracle database?

Tags: linux, oracle, server

All I found on the Internet is that you need to check the value of the initialization parameter. It is equal to the value of `DB` in the following screenshot:
[image]

Does this mean that my audit is enabled? If not, why not? How do I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that audit is enabled. `Value = DB` means:

> Enables database auditing and directs standard audit records to the database audit trail (SYS.AUD$), except for records that are always written to the operating system audit trail. (This value is the default if you created the database using Database Configuration Assistant. Otherwise, the default is NONE.)

---

```
Value = NONE
```

> Disables standard auditing.

---

You'll find much more information in documentation ([Auditing database activity](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50522)); this is for 11g, pick one for your database version.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Auditing is actually a two-part question.  First, setting the AUDIT_TRAIL parameter enables logging, in so much as it specifies where the audit records are to be written.  But you still need to specify *what* is to be audited.  That's where the SQL 'AUDIT' command comes in.

Comment: But what about audit_sys_operations?

Comment: _"But what about audit_sys_operations?"_   What about it?  What did you read about it in the docs?

Comment: If the value is `true`, then these operations will be included, they are not required to be included? Is it enough that `Value = DB`?

Comment: Quoting from the docs, under AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS : _"The audit records are written to the operating system's audit trail. "_ That's unconditional. The _ARE_ written to the OS's audit trail. That would override anything from AUDIT_TRAIL.